# onkeydown event on an ASPX page

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am trying to add a `onKeyDown` event to an aspx page in .NET . Since I don't have access to the body tag I tried doing something like this:

```
if (window.addEventListener) {
    window.addEventListener('onkeydown', checkEnter(event), false);
}
else {
    window.attachEvent('onkeydown', checkEnter(), false);
}

function checkEnter(event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
        ShowList();
    }
}
```

However, the `event` turns out undefined this way. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: What is the reason behind capturing Enter key like this?

Comment: @Win So that a 'search' functionality works, rather than having the user click the 'Ok' button.

Comment: @ArtF FWIW you should be checking `event.which == 13 || event.keyCode == 13`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First mistake is the way you are binding the events..

```
            window.addEventListener('onkeydown', checkEnter(event), false);
```

**You are executing the function at the time of binding it.**       **-------------------                                  ^**

You need to just assign the function to the event.

`window.addEventListener('keydown', checkEnter, false);`

**Also the event type should be "keydown"**

You need not worry about passing in the *event* object to the function as it is passed in by default.

Comment: How would I keep it from being executed?

Answer (score 0):

You could easily achieve the same result using jQuery.

```
<script type="text/javascript" 
   src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).keypress(function (e) {
        if (e.which == 13) {
            alert("Enter key is pressed.");
        }
    });
</script>
```

Or user Panel control's DefaultButton to capture the enter key *which is a prefer method if you use Button control*.

```
<asp:Panel runat="server" ID="SearchPanel" DefaultButton="SearchButton">
    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="SearchButton" Text="Search" />
</asp:Panel>
```

Answer (score 0):

Two things you'll want to change:

- Remove "on" from "onkeydown"
- No need to pass in "event" to "checkEnter"

  ```
      if (window.addEventListener) {
          window.addEventListener('keydown', checkEnter, false);
      }
      else {
          window.attachEvent('keydown', checkEnter, false);
      }

      function checkEnter(event) {
          if (event.keyCode == 13) {
              ShowList();
          }
      }
  ```

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener